# How to separate different input formats from the same text file with Python

Tags: python, input, text

I'm new to programming and python and I'm looking for a way to distinguish between two input formats in the same input file text file. For example, let's say I have an input file like so where values are comma-separated:

> 5
>   Washington,A,10
>   New York,B,20
>   Seattle,C,30
>   Boston,B,20
>   Atlanta,D,50
>   2
>   New York,5
>   Boston,10

Where the format is **N** followed by **N** lines of Data1, and **M** followed by **M** lines of Data2. I tried opening the file, reading it line by line and storing it into one single list, but I'm not sure how to go about to produce 2 lists for Data1 and Data2, such that I would get:

> Data1 = ["Washington,A,10", "New York,B,20", "Seattle,C,30", "Boston,B,20", "Atlanta,D,50"]
>   Data2 = ["New York,5", "Boston,10"]

My initial idea was to iterate through the list until I found an integer **i**, remove the integer from the list and continue for the next **i** iterations all while storing the subsequent values in a separate list, until I found the next integer and then repeat. However, this would destroy my initial list. Is there a better way to separate the two data formats in different lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**`itertools.islice`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import islice

string = """
5
Washington,A,10
New York,B,20
Seattle,C,30
Boston,B,20
Atlanta,D,50
2
New York,5
Boston,10
"""

result = [[x for x in islice(parts, idx + 1, idx + 1 + int(line))]
          for parts in [string.split("\n")]
          for idx, line in enumerate(parts)
          if line.isdigit()]

print(result)
```

This yields

```
[['Washington,A,10', 'New York,B,20', 'Seattle,C,30', 'Boston,B,20', 'Atlanta,D,50'], ['New York,5', 'Boston,10']]
```

For a file, you need to change it to:

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as f:
    result = [[x for x in islice(parts, idx + 1, idx + 1 + int(line))]
              for parts in [f.read().split("\n")]
              for idx, line in enumerate(parts)
              if line.isdigit()]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track.
If you want to preserve the original list here, you don't actually have to remove integer **i**; you can just go on to the next item.

Code:

```
originalData = []
formattedData = []

with open("data.txt", "r") as f :
    f = list(f)
    originalData = f
    i = 0
    while i < len(f): # Iterate through every line
        try:
            n = int(f[i]) # See if line can be cast to an integer
            originalData[i] = n # Change string to int in original
            formattedData.append([])
            for j in range(n):
                i += 1
                item = f[i].replace('\n', '')
                originalData[i] = item # Remove newline char in original
                formattedData[-1].append(item)
        except ValueError:
            print("File has incorrect format")
        i += 1

print(originalData)
print(formattedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will produce a list `results` which is equal to `[Data1, Data2]`.

The code assumes that the number of entries specified is exactly the amount that there is. That means that for a file like this, it will not work.

> 2
>   New York,5
>   Boston,10
>   Seattle,30

The code:

```py
# get the data from the text file
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

results = []
index = 0

while index < len(lines):
    # Find the start and end values.
    start = index + 1
    end = start + int(lines[index])

    # Everything from the start up to and excluding the end index gets added
    results.append(lines[start:end])

    # Update the index
    index = end
```